# ValueError: Unknown metric function : TP_count

Tags: python, keras

I am getting this kind of ValueError while am trying to build a BGRU model for my project purpose. Please let me know why this type of error occuring. A part of code is shown below :

```
def build_model(maxlen, vector_dim, layers, dropout):
    print('Build model...')
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(maxlen, vector_dim)))

    for i in range(1, layers):
        model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(units=256, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', return_sequences=True)))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(units=256, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid')))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adamax', metrics=['TP_count', 'FP_count', 'FN_count', 'precision', 'recall', 'fbeta_score'])

    model.summary()

    return model
```

```
    def main(traindataSet_path, testdataSet_path, realtestpath, weightpath, resultpath, batch_size, maxlen, vector_dim, layers, dropout):
        print("Loading data...")

    model = build_model(maxlen, vector_dim, layers, dropout)

the error occuring is shown as below :

    Using TensorFlow backend.
    Loading data...
    Build model...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "bgru.py", line 220, in <module>
        main(traindataSetPath, testdataSetPath, realtestdataSetPath, weightPath, resultPath, batchSize, maxLen, vectorDim, layers, dropout)
      File "bgru.py", line 51, in main
        model = build_model(maxlen, vector_dim, layers, dropout)
      File "bgru.py", line 41, in build_model
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adamax', metrics=['TP_count', 'FP_count', 'FN_count', 'precision', 'recall', 'fbeta_score'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 439, in compile
        handle_metrics(output_metrics)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 396, in handle_metrics
        metric_fn = metrics_module.get(metric)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 75, in get
        return deserialize(str(identifier))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 67, in deserialize
        printable_module_name='metric function')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 165, in deserialize_keras_object
        ':' + function_name)
    ValueError: Unknown metric function:TP_count
```

How could I change this error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is obvious, you are using undocumented metrics which are not there.

```
def build_model(maxlen, vector_dim, layers, dropout):
    print('Build model...')
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(maxlen, vector_dim)))

    for i in range(1, layers):
        model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(units=256, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', return_sequences=True)))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(units=256, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid')))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adamax', metrics=['accuracy', 'mae'])

    model.summary()

    return model
```

Here is a list of available metrics: https://keras.io/metrics/

You can create your own metrics too, but they don't go inside compile function as a list of string instead just pass the function name.

```
import keras.backend as K

def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', mean_pred])
```

Comment: do you know why i am getting following error: AttributeError: 'ProgbarLogger' object has no attribute 'log_values'